# parser error exception when trying to export to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

So i could really use a clue as to why this is happening and how to solve it. I'm trying to export a crystal report to pdf using the code found below:

```
protected void ExportRptButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.ReportParamsSvc.ReportDefinition rptCfg = SelectedReport;
            if ( null != SelectedReport )
            {
                rptParams.Clear();
                rptParams = null;

                // Get the report document
                // string filePath = Server.MapPath( @"~\Reports\" + SelectedReport.FileName + ".rpt" );
                // Declare a new Crystal Report Document object and load the report file into the report document.
                ReportDocument rptDoc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
                ConfigureCrystalReports(rptDoc);
                // repDoc.Load(rptFileName);

                // AddParameters();
                // Set the report parameters the report object.
                //LoadReportParameterValues(SelectedReport);
                LoadParameterFields(rptDoc);
                // Set the static text fields in the report object.
                LoadStaticTextFields(rptDoc);

                try
                {
                    if (rptDoc.IsLoaded)
                    {
                        // Stop buffering the response
                        Response.Buffer = false;
                        // Clear the response content and headers
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.ClearHeaders();
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                        // Export the Report to Response stream in PDF format and file name Customers
                        rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "DirectAccessReport");
                        // Response.Filter.Flush();
                        // Response.Flush();
                        // rptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "~/PDF_Folder");
                        // There are other format options available such as Word, Excel, CVS, and HTML in the ExportFormatType Enum given by crystal reports
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException ex)
                {
                    logger.ErrorFormat("Could not export to pdf: threading! {0}", ex);
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    logger.ErrorFormat("Could not export to pdf! {0}", ex);                  
                }
            }
        }
```

The "ConfigureCrystalReports" just gets the filepath of the report.

The "LoadParameterFields" populates the parameters for the report and i'm pretty sure it works since its the same code i use to populate the parameters when opening the report in the CRViewer. But if you would like to see what it does then let me know and i will add it.

The same can be said about the "LoadStaticTextFields" which just gets the text values of the labels in the report.

The error i am receiving can be found in the img below:

[image]

my best guess as to where the problem is occurring is in the try loop. as you can see i've tried several different approaches with the Response fields from most of the commented out code.

I've spent a great deal of time looking for an answer for this and most people say that i have to remove all of my Response.Write() calls from my code, however I am not using Response.Write() anywhere in my code.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try not clearing the headers..

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it's still throwing a parser error.